# Wrong number of segments in token (Refresh Token)

Tags: php, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

The problem is that when I request refresh token for `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly` and 
run

```
$client->refreshToken(<TOKEN>); 
$client->verifyIdToken();
```

it returns error

> ("wrong number of segments in token").

The strange thing is that when I request the refresh token for array

```
('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login')
```

it works like charm.

Code:

```
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login'));
$client->setRequestVisibleActions('http://schema.org/AddAction');
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setApprovalPrompt('force');
```

Can anyone offer an explanation?

Comment: Is this the php client library you are using? or are you coding this manually?

Comment: yes, I use the client library

Answer (score -1):

I would check what `<TOKEN>` is set to. My guess its its probably set to nothing because `analytics.readonly` is not a valid scope. 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly' is a valid scope because that's the pure url for the scope.

if you are using the PHP client library you should be adding scope like this

```
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY);
```

[Hello Analytics php tutorial](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/web-php)

Comment: That`s the scope I use. I shortened it when I wrote this question. The <token> is not empty.

Comment: you should post the exact code you are using not shorten it or we cant help you find your errors.